# I followed all instructions for locating ChromeDriver. Why can Watir not find ChromeDriver?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I use Windows 7. I want to try watir-webdriver with Chrome.

I got the message:  Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from...

I followed the instructions here:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

I placed the EXE in the recommended location. I added the location to the "path" variable in "Environment Variables". (Not the PATH variable.)

I still get the same message as before.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: If I recall correctly, when I had the same problem, rebooting the computer (after adding the path variable) solved the problem.

Comment: I tried that just now. No success. I simply started the server manually. It's now running in a DOS console. Still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently wrote instructions how to [drive Chrome on Windows](https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md#chrome). Does it work if you follow the instructions?

Comment: I followed the instruction `In short, move the file to Ruby folder, probably C:\Ruby200\bin.` (No reboot.) As a result, I can now advance to exactly the same failure point as I do with IE and FF. So, I suppose that qualifies as a "pass". The failure will be the subject of another stackOverflow question.